# Shouldn't class have preference over * selector

Tags: html, css

```
<head>
    <link href="scribble.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
    
<body>
    <a> text </a>
    <p class="para"> 
        <ul>text</ul>
        <a>text1 </a>
    </p>
</body>
```

My css goes like this:

```
*{background-color:#ccc;}

.para{background-color:red;}
```

For some Reason only the universal selector is being applied and all backgrodun is gray. Why? Shouldn't the class have precedence over the universal selector?

Comment: Your `<ul>` and `<a>`  elements don't actually have the `.para` class. The only selector they match is `*`. You are thinking that CSS inheritance, where certain elements inherit properties from their parent(s), would take precedence, but it does not. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance

Comment: Your `<ul>` isn't inside the `<p>` element once it's rendered – since that would be invalid html – and the text of your `<ul>` isn't inside the that element, since text-nodes aren't valid in a `<ul>` outside of `<li>` elements. Right-click, inspect element and you might see what the problem is (admittedly I haven't checked this, since I'm on my phone, but I think I'm correct in saying your html renders differently than you expect).

Comment: Note that a list inside a paragraph is invalid HTML

Comment: It would be easier to drill down into this phenomenon if you could use valid HTML. And try .para * in the stylesheet. It still does not change the inner elements' backgrounds - but swap in a div instead of a p element and it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what it's doing.

```
<p class="para"> 
   <ul>text</ul>
   <a>text1</a>
</p>
```

Only `.para` has a background color of `red` so *only* that particular element will receive that attribute. However, the universal selector is explicity telling all other items to have a background color of `#ccc`. Since the `ul`/`a` elements do not use that class, it means those elements will honor the universal selector `background-color:#ccc;`. CSS would assume you mean something like:

```
ul, a {background-color:#ccc;}
```

If you were to add any text to the `.para`, however, it would have that `red` background color, e.g.

```css
* {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.para {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="para"> 
  Hello
   <ul>text</ul>
   <a>text1</a>
</p>
```

Also having those elements use the `.para` class will make them red.

```css
* {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.para {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<p class="para"> 
   <ul class="para">text</ul>
   <a class="para">text1</a>
</p>
```